# How can I count the occurrence of all the names in the names list which have the letter 'i' as their second letter

Tags: python, list

I am trying to count the occurrence of the name in a name_list with letter 'i' as their second letter using a nested loop.

```
 def print_count(names_list):
    for name in names_list:
        count = 0
        for i in range(len(name)):
            if name[i] == 'i' and i == 1:
                count = count + 1

    print(count)

names = ["Cody", "Baldassar", "Delilah", "Vinnie", "Leila", "Zac", "Aiden", "Zaynab"]
print_count(names)
```

My expected output should be: 2 but i got 0 instead.

Comment: You are resetting `count` to zero on each iteration of the loop.  Only the very last name in the list can possibly add to the final count.  (And why are you looping through the characters of each name?  You can directly get the character of interest as `name[1]`.)

Comment: Next time, you could try to run the code in https://pythontutor.com/ and learn how to debug by watching execution in steps.

Answer (score 4):

**Update**

The fastest solution so far is @KellyBundy's idea of using a slice:

```py
>>> len([s for s in names if s[1:2] == 'i'])
2
```

**Original answer** (twice slower!)

You can express that simply and efficiently:

```py
>>> len([s for s in names if s[1:].startswith('i')])
2
```

**Why?**

The argument of `len` is a list comprehension. It is the original list, filtered by the condition "must have a second letter, and that second letter must be `'i'`":

```py
>>> [s for s in names if s[1:2] == 'i']
['Vinnie', 'Aiden']
```

**But is it safe?**

Q: "What if a word is empty or has only one letter? For sure `s[1]` would raise `IndexError`, right?"

A: It is safe. Yes, `s[1]` would raise if `s` is empty or contains a single char, but `s[1:2]` is just fine:

```py
>>> 'foo'[1:2]
'o'

>>> 'f'[1:2]
''

>>> ''[1:2]
''
```

**Variations and timings**

```py
# setup: generate a large list of random names
import numpy as np

n = 1_000_000
names = list(map(''.join, np.random.choice(list('abcdefghijkl'), (n, 10))))

# 1. ***current winner*** @KellyBundy's idea to use a slice
%timeit len([s for s in names if s[1:2] == 'i'])
# 71.8 ms ± 32.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

# 2. @Blckknght's suggestion, len of list comprehension version
%timeit len([s for s in names if len(s) > 1 and s[1] == 'i'])
# 98.2 ms ± 82.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

# 3. @Blckknght's suggestion, generator version
%timeit sum(len(s) > 1 and s[1] == 'i' for s in names)
# 105 ms ± 24.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

# 4. @AndrejKesely's solution
%timeit sum(n[1] == "i" for n in names if len(n) > 1)
# 106 ms ± 77.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

# 5. original answer
%timeit len([s for s in names if s[1:].startswith('i')])
# 140 ms ± 821 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

# 6. generator
%timeit sum(1 for s in names if s[1:].startswith('i'))
# 141 ms ± 27.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

# 7. sum of booleans, as list comprehension
%timeit sum([s[1:].startswith('i') for s in names])
# 154 ms ± 145 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

# 8. sum of booleans, as generator
%timeit sum(s[1:].startswith('i') for s in names)
#163 ms ± 544 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Notice how operating on a generator instead of on a list comprehension sometimes takes longer (# 3. vs # 2. and # 8. vs # 7.). That surprised me when I heard about it a few years ago.

**Update** (including @Blckknght and @AndrejKesely ideas)

Both of these solutions are about 40% faster than my initial code (kudos!).

**Update 2** Including @KellyBundy's slice idea

That idea (new # 1.) gets us another 20% cut off of the previous winner (# 2. @Blckknght's suggestion together with using len of a list comprehension). It is the new overall winner. In my tests, I found that using a constant slice (`slc = slice(1, 2)` and `s[slc]`) is indistinguishable from the expression in # 1.

Comment: It can be done in `generator` way too - `print(sum(1 for name in names if name[1] =='i'))`

Comment: @DanielHao operating on a generator is sometimes slower than operating on a list comprehension. In this case (and in Python 3.9), the two take the same time. But see the variations (3) and (4) in the edited answer.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the `performance` info.  Originally my post is just to show another approach, not to empahsis perf. But just run it again with your method/data - In [5]: `%timeit sum(1 for name in names if name[1] =='i')` 
`64.5 ms ± 5.22 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each) `  IT seems to be faster than other versions?

Comment: Actually I did `upvote` it earlier... ;-)  Running in 3.9 and 3.10 both show same results. I guess `s[1:]` and `startswith` will also have some impact.

Comment: Might I suggest `len(s) > 1 and s[1] == 'i'` as the condition to test, rather than using a slice and a method call? I suspect it will outperform all the versions of your current code.

Comment: @Blckknght: good idea; used in a list comprehension construct, it was briefly the winner (faster than if used in a generator). But KellyBundy's solution (slice) is another 20% faster.

Comment: Where did you create `slc`? If it's not faster, then I suspect you made it a global rather than local variable.

Answer (score 2):

Add `count = 0` above the for loop. Otherwise, you reset it to zero each time. In addition, you do not need the second loop.

```
def print_count(names_list):
    count = 0
    for name in names_list:
        if len(name) > 1 and name[1] == 'i':
            count += 1
    print(count)

names = ["Cody", "Baldassar", "Delilah", "Vinnie", "Leila", "Zac", "Aiden", "Zaynab"]
print_count(names)
```

Comment: Hi Ayaz Samadli, welcome to the site. This answer is quite good, though I've edited slightly to fix the code formatting.  The one issue this code has is that it will break if any of the strings in the `names_list` has fewer than two characters (which, granted, is unlikely for real names). You can fix this by checking `len(name) > 1` just before you do `name[1] == 'i'`, since the indexing in that expression will fail for very short names. If you combine the two conditions with `and`, the short-circuiting behavior will prevent any exceptions.

Comment: Hi Blckkgnht. Thank you very much for the fix and suggestion. I added your suggestion to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are setting count to zero for every name because you placed `count=0` inside the loop that loops over the names. The way it is now, the count that is printed only contains the count of the last name in the list.

If you move it out of the loop your code will work.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution:

```py
print(sum(n[1] == "i" for n in names if len(n) > 1))
```

Prints:

```
2
```

---

Quick benchmark:

```py
from timeit import timeit

names = [
    "Cody",
    "Baldassar",
    "Delilah",
    "Vinnie",
    "Leila",
    "Zac",
    "Aiden",
    "Zaynab",
]

def fn1():
    return len([s for s in names if s[1:].startswith("i")])


def fn2():
    return sum(n[1] == "i" for n in names if len(n) > 1)


t1 = timeit(lambda: fn1(), number=1_000_000)
t2 = timeit(lambda: fn2(), number=1_000_000)

print(t1)
print(t2)
```

Prints on my machine (AMD 3700X, Pyhton 3.9.7):

```
1.5491739970020717
1.2039272840047488
```

Answer (score 1):

Some more solutions/benchmarks:

```
 625 us ± 3.9 us  [n[i12] for n in names].count("i")
 632 us ± 3.5 us  len([0 for n in names if "i" in n[i12]])
 654 us ± 2.3 us  len([0 for n in names if n[i12] == "i"])
 657 us ± 4.0 us  len([n for n in names if n[i12] == "i"])
 691 us ± 3.9 us  sum(1 for n in names if n[i12] == "i")
 736 us ± 5.9 us  [*map(ig, names)].count("i")
 777 us ± 5.5 us  countOf(map(ig, names), "i")
 837 us ± 5.1 us  sum(1 for n in names if n[1:2] == "i")
1038 us ± 1.6 us  len([s for s in names if s.startswith("i", 1)])
1206 us ± 5.0 us  sum(n[1:2] == "i" for n in names)
1229 us ± 3.2 us  sum(n[1] == "i" for n in names if len(n) > 1)
1594 us ± 4.9 us  len([s for s in names if s[1:].startswith("i")])
```

Benchmark code ([Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVTbitswEH3XVwx5sbSY1E4vFEMKvTwW@rL0ocYUrT1KRG3ZSMq2IexH9Rf6Y@lItneT0CXNizWjc@acUTQa9n7bm5dvB3s8Ktt34HWH2oPuht76KUrB4oDSs4iw0jT0mRBuu1OqxXHLeem187p283aH0qSUb/CeMYd@N8AakiQZ8f2AVvrezmjtsdug92hTqPud8V8UY0Z26IhVMqDf4mPf7BfpuP4g20Y6J@2c@IStbuV2Dr9qYzTO0WekvTn4Jut5@V43aJ7yeyPvKKrgBvIsyxjT@YrkXatr5HkKK8H0hhJPZjkhBAtdsbpvHs0mLRpeOlDUIB2IgbETrcCVeVEt6bSsdz@13/KFXohKJMFD4nYdN2VewXoNlI90c0YPdY2Ad5BPlOeFLkRSolzoFKtnlE5g@T9MnFGvYumELrDRc3YNXF1DB98hjqQztPnf2tNN450cuN6kU/fpiddy4p0XrJaRyU9wN@c1LhAVY6FCHSrEi1IQCX9hzeNkCIoGqwmP97LlNVmoBVHCfYpwdkurgyqgHK2oUEi5B9Yg/dVciVDPx@vnb3J8E0E@gBxNFzb8tlSVKIvXVUVAS5qW@MkhSIZB5d4JUbx6gJ2DP7/hEMc2JItlrmI2GTv4HmrSO7ChgciyKDu9A1y50MaJuyLOldl1d2jJWZ7F2NNyfFy4ovchtJ9OoPX4EfBiSkRCsL6Uw4Cm4V6wR4GpM@VS@IH7tROj3niO4UxSUOJ4/As)):

```
from timeit import timeit, repeat
from random import shuffle
from statistics import mean, stdev

setup = '''
from operator import itemgetter, countOf

names = [
    "Cody",
    "Baldassar",
    "Delilah",
    "Vinnie",
    "Leila",
    "Zac",
    "Aiden",
    "Zaynab",
] * 1000

i12 = slice(1, 2)
ig = itemgetter(i12)
'''

codes = [
  'len([s for s in names if s[1:].startswith("i")])',
  'sum(n[1] == "i" for n in names if len(n) > 1)',
  'len([s for s in names if s.startswith("i", 1)])',
  'sum(n[1:2] == "i" for n in names)',
  'sum(1 for n in names if n[1:2] == "i")',
  'sum(1 for n in names if n[i12] == "i")',
  'len([0 for n in names if n[i12] == "i"])',
  'len([0 for n in names if "i" in n[i12]])',
  'len([n for n in names if n[i12] == "i"])',
  'countOf(map(ig, names), "i")',
  '[n[i12] for n in names].count("i")',
  '[*map(ig, names)].count("i")',
]

for c in codes:
  exec(setup)
  print(eval(c), c)

fs = codes
T = {f: [] for f in fs}
def s(f):
  ts = [t*1e6 for t in sorted(T[f])[:5]]
  return f'{int(mean(ts)):4} us ± {stdev(ts):.1f} us '

for _ in range(100):
  shuffle(fs)
  for f in fs:
    number = 10
    t = timeit(f, setup, number=number) / number
    T[f].append(t)
for f in sorted(fs, key=s):
    print(s(f), f)
```

Comment: Very nice -- great idea to use a slice constant (`i12`).

Comment: This answer keeps getting better and better...  Clever idea using `list.count('i')`. But in my tests (I switched now to a setup with 5 million random strings to better see timing differences), it is actually slower than `len([s for s in names if s[1:2] == 'i'])`.

Comment: @PierreD Added an even faster one now. And I see [compiling constant slices to constants](https://bugs.python.org/issue42454) has been suggested but not yet done. Not sure how these compare to your benchmark, btw, since you have relatively fewer positive cases (an advantage for early-filtering solutions like `sum(1 for if cond)` instead of `sum(cond for)`), larger results (could negatively affect list-builders), and longer strings (very slight advantage for `startswith(..., 1)` over `s[1:]`).

Comment: Good point on the effect of setup and resulting hit rate, string length. I'd go with your solution that is \#&nbsp;1 in my tests -- it is eminently readable and should be very fast no matter the setup. Also, I noted no difference between a `slc` variable vs explicit `[1:2]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
def print_count(names_list):
    count = 0
    for name in names_list:
        
        for i in range(len(name)):
            if name[i] == 'i' and i == 1:
               
                count = count + 1

    print(count)

names = ["Cody", "Baldassar", "Delilah", "Vinnie", "Leila", "Zac", "Aiden", "Zaynab"]
print_count(names)
```

Comment: Hi Aouri, welcome to Stack Overflow. I've edited your answer to improve the code formatting, but please feel free to [edit] it further yourself if I messed anything up. You might improve this answer by explaining a bit what your have changed. Code only answers are not necessarily unacceptable here, but they can always be better with some added explanation. Sometimes you can fit the explanation into comments inside the code, though that's not generally necessary or even a good idea.

Comment: Thanks @Blckknght , I am a new member and this is my first time. I would surely improve Next time

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).